# When are edges adjacent?

Tags: graphs, terminology

What conditions must be fulfilled for two edges of a graph to be called adjacent?

I found a lot about adjacent nodes, but our CS course script refers to adjacent edges, with no explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two edges are adjacent if they're incident on the same vertex:

> Two edges are *adjacent* if they have exactly one common endvertex.
> —Bollobás, *Modern Graph Theory* (Springer, 1998; page 2).
>
> Two edges $e\neq f$ are *adjacent* if they have an end in common.
> —Diestel, *Graph Theory* (2nd Edition, Springer, 2000; page 3).

Comment: So this basically means two edges are adjacent if of both of them share at least one common vertex?

Comment: Yes. (Note that, unless you're considering multigraphs, two distinct edges can't have _two_ common vertices.)